# Is this function a contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I have real valued function defined by $g(t)=t-d(t)$ where $d(t)$ is a function such that $0 <d (t)\leq h $ and $d^\prime (t)\leq m <1.$ From these data one can clearly prove that $g(t)$ is a bijective and strictly increasing function. Now can one find any relation between the distances between the elements in the domain and codomain. I am clueless. Any hint would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for $g(t)$ to be a contraction, you'd need there to exist some $k$ in $(0,1)$ such that, for any choice of $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$, you get $|g(x)-g(y)| = |x-y - (d(x)-d(y))| \leq k|x-y|$.

With this in mind, here's a hint: can you find a function $d(t)$ satisfying the conditions such that $d(t)$ gets arbitrarily small as $t$ gets large? In particular, if you can get  $d(t)\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, then you can show that for large enough $x$ and $y$, the quantity $\frac{|g(x)-g(y)|}{|x-y|}$ gets as close to $1$ as you like (and in particular, would eventually get bigger than any choice of $k$, so $g$ would not be a contraction).